# Redshift insert/delete queries producing inconsistent results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an ETL process running on Redshift and one of the insert/delete sequences has provided very strange results. Here is the sequence of queries:

1. Store unique identifiers for deletion:

```
create table tmp_delete_mtk 
diststyle all
as 
select distinct master_tk from std_clnt_master 
where master_num in (select master_num from tmp_delete_master_nums)
```

2. Insert rows to delete in another table for use later in the process

```
insert into relink_fields 
select * 
from all_linking_fields a
where a.document_id in (select master_tk from tmp_delete_mtk)
```

Query 2 inserts 152,177 rows from all_linking_fields. The document_id field is a unique key of all_linking_fields

3. Delete inserted rows from all_linking_fields

```
delete from all_linking_fields 
where document_id in (select master_tk from tmp_delete_mtk)
```

Query 3 removes 153,328 rows from all_linking_fields. The problem is that the delete query removes more rows from all_linking_fields than are inserted to relink_fields. Since queries 2 and 3 are using the same key to select the inserts and deletes, respectively, I do not understand how the row count could differ between the insert and delete. Please note that these queries are run sequentially and the rows of all_linking_fields are not changed during this sequence.

I have also been unable to reproduce this bug on a restored snapshot of the cluster. Any ideas of what could be causing this bug?

Comment: how do you get the numbers, hekn with SELET COUNT(*), engines are notorious bad at counting and the numbers are estimates

Comment: I use the rowcount attribute of the cursor after the query is executed: 
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount

The deletes/inserts are in fact different, since if I reinserted relink_fields to all_linking_fields, all_linking_fields has less rows than before the delete sequence.

Comment: When you say that "document_id field is a unique key of all_linking_fields" is this a statement about the table DDL?  Or have you performed SQL checks to make sure that there are no duplicates in this column?  Redshift doesn't enforce uniqueness (no clustered DBs do AFAIK).  Many get tripped up by this and it could explain your issue as well.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the comment. We do not specify that "document_id" is a unique field in the redshift table DDL, so I'm not sure how the query planner could get tripped up by this. We enforce uniqueness via the query patterns on the table and we check for uniqueness at the end of each iteration. The "all_linking_fields" table is distributed and sorted by "document_id", however.